# IDA Pro: Export identified array to c/c++

Tags: ida

I have a couple of global structs in a binary which are basically tables (arrays) of some values - i wish to export these to c/c++ format arrays but i did not found any way. Is this possible in any way or do i have to copy all binary data starting from a specific offset and convert it manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDA can make structures look better than the raw data.
But to export it as c/c++ like data initializers, you would have to write some idc or idapython script t convert the data.

Comment: btw, in the most recent version ( ida v6.3 + hexrays decompiler v1.7 ), the decompiler is capable of decompiling data initializers.

Comment: no, i should probably rephrase my answer as: 'C' style initializers.  hexrays does not decompile back to c++ code.